# Hide Model Popup After showing alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, model

I want to hide the model popup which is showing at the center   at the time when I am showing the alert message on the top of the page.

This one is my popup

```
<div class="Model_Div" id="Model" style="display:none;">
    <div class="inside_Div">
        <span id="modelBox"></span>
        <div class="Model_Button">
            <span><button class="sb-btn" ng-click="reset()">Keep Working</button></span>
            <span><a ng-click="vm.setSignOut()" class="sb-btn a_Button" href="/App/LogOff" target="_self">Sign Out</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to hide it using different ways like

```
1. document.getElementsByClassName("Model_Div")[0].style.display = "none";
 2. $('#Model').hide();
```

but not succeeded

It is showing like this

[image]

Comment: its not look like your popup, but a browser alert. did you do somewhere in js `alert(Session ended due to inactivity)`?

Comment: I am talking the popup which is showing in the center

Comment: nothing will work during the alert shown. it's pause all the processes

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not the best (I hope someone will tell you something better), but this should help

```css
.modal {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <h4>Modal title</h4>
  <button class="modal__btn">Exit</button>
</div>

<script>
  const modalBtn = document.querySelector('.modal__btn')
  const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
  
  modalBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    modal.style.display = 'none'
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('message')
    }, 0)
    
  })
  
</script>
```